# Why does '12345'.count('') return 6 and not 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

```
>>> '12345'.count('')
6
```

Why does this happen? If there are only 5 characters in that string, why is the count function returning one more?

Also, is there a more effective way of counting characters in a string?

Comment: Think fence posts and fence panels. Each panel has a character on it. Each post has no character on it.

Comment: Simple failure to read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count). Not sure why so many upvotes. -1

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The documentation is off course not in sync with the implementation. As per the documentation `Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end].`, the result should had been 4.

Comment: @Abhijit Where do you see the difference between the implementation and the documentation? In my point  of view, that sentence makes it clear, why the result is 6. Since "start" and "end" are _inclusive_ the empty string infront (and behind) them counts too.

Comment: @Abhijit: `start` and `end` take default values (actually `None`, but logically equivalent to `0` and `len('12345')`). So there are 6 "occurrences" of the empty substring in the range `[start, end]`, specifically `[0:0]`, `[1:1]`, ... `[5:5]`. If the range specified were `[start, end)`, excluding one endpoint, then we wouldn't have `[5:5]`, and if the range were `(start, end)` excluding both endpoints then we also wouldn't have `[0:0]`, in which case 4 would be right. But if the definition excluded endpoints then `'abc'.count('abc')` would be 0, which would be rather surprising ;-)

Comment: @Tom: `end` is not included: *"Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation."* i.e., `s[start:end]` contains `s[start]`, .., `s[end-1]`. It does not contain `s[end]` e.g., `'aaa'.count('a', 0, 1) == 1`, not  `2` but notice that `'aaa'.count('', 0, 1) == 2`

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`count` returns how many times an object occurs in a list, so if you count occurrences of `''` you get 6 because the empty string is at the beginning, end, and in between each letter.

Use the `len` function to find the length of a string.

Comment: I think using iterable Object is more appropriate instead of `list`!

Comment: "how many times an object occurs in a list" is a vague notion: if I concatenate 100 times the empty list, do I get `count(s,'')` to be 100? Also, "occurs" may lead one to thinks that `s[i]` is `object` for some `i` -- confusing membership and sub-list. Perhaps it would be less ambiguous to say that `count(s,z)` returns the number of indices `0<=i<=len(s)` such that `s[i:]` starts with `z`.

Comment: The op ask about a string not a list. So from the documentation  [str.count](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count) "Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub"

Comment: why is there one `''` in between letters instead of five or none at all?

Comment: I don't think it answers the question: `list('a').count('') == 0`, but `'a'.count('') == 2`. It looks like an artifact of the current implementation because `'a'.split('')` fails with `ValueError`

Answer (score 28):

That is because there are six different substrings that are the empty string: Before the 1, between the numbers, and after the 5.

If you want to count characters use `len` instead:

```
>>> len("12345")
5
```

Comment: It explains nothing. The answer could  have been zero because there are zero items such as `s[i] == ''`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Items such that `s[i]` is the empty string and empty substrings are different notions altogether. A substring can be chosen such that it has zero characters, and this can be done in six distinct ways (from index 0 length 0, from index 1 length 0, etc)

Comment: yes. My mistake (`s[i]` implies `len(sub) == 1` and therefore can't be used for an empty string). But it still doesn't explain the result. It is clear that the implementation counts `s[i:i+len(sub)]` non-overlapping slices in `s` that are equal to `sub`. It doesn't explain why `s[end:end+len(sub)]` is included: usually `s[start:end]` slice does not include `end` position.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian If `len(sub)` is equal to zero, then the slice is `s[i:i]`, which is empty (since there are no elements such that their index is >= i but also < i.

Comment: And how does it explain that `i == end` is allowed? I understand that `s[end:end]` by itself is valid but the `str.count()` docs explicitly say that `start`,`end` should be interpreted as in slice notation i.e. `i<end` and therefore `s[end:end]` should not be included in the count.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian It would probably make sense to head into the Python documents at this point. My understanding is that `i==end` is valid but in most cases meaningless (empty slice). Python isn't my primary language so I don't know how to better explain my reasoning, or even to check if my reasoning is, in fact, 100% rigorous and correct.

Answer (score 25):

How many pieces do you get if you cut a string five times?

```
---|---|---|---|---|---     -> 6 pieces
```

The same thing is happening here. It counts the empty string after the `5` also.

`len('12345')` is what you should use.

Comment: it would be the answer if `'a'.split('')` were working.

Answer (score 6):

The most common way is to use `len('12345')`. It returns the number of characters in a given string - in this case 5.

Answer (score 1):

Count and Len are two very different things. Len simply prints the length of the string (hence the name 'Len'), while Count iterates through the string or list and gives you the number of times an object occurs, which counts the beginning and end of the string as well as in between each letter.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same reason why it makes sense for `''.count('')` to return `1`, not `0`.

Comment: why `1` instead of `0`, why not `100`. I pretty sure `0*100 == 0`